# Removing trailing zeros in case statement

Tags: sql, t-sql

I've been trying to remove the trailing zeros from a column of a table. It works well when I try to remove the zeros from the column. However, when I use it with a case statement (to remove the zeros when a flag is turned on, and to keep them when a flag is turned off) it doesn't work properly. It doesn't recognize the flag. For example, I've hard coded the column as a constant value; while 1=0 (false), it is retrieving the value removing the zeros. It should be true in the else statement.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 1=0 THEN cast(CAST(123.45000 AS decimal(6,2)) as float)  
ELSE   
'123.456700'   
END


SELECT CASE WHEN 1=0 THEN CONVERT(DOUBLE PRECISION, 123.456700) 
ELSE   
'123.456700'   
END
```

Why is this happening? Can anyone help me with this?

The above is well explained by @Tim below.

However, it doesn't remove the zeros at all in a table. It doesn't recognize the flag at all. Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE #tablea 
(item CHAR(2), name VARCHAR(10), amount DECIMAL(9,2)) 

INSERT INTO #tablea 
VALUES ('AB', 'D1', 1.10), 
       ('AB', 'D2', 1.00), 
       ('AB', 'D3', 0.90), 
       ('AB', 'D4', 0.09)    

DECLARE @flag INT = 1

SELECT CASE WHEN @flag = 1 
THEN CAST(CAST(amount AS DECIMAL(6,2)) AS VARCHAR(max))
ELSE amount END 
FROM #tablea
```

Comment: You can't combine columns types in a CASE statement so instead the database is making the result of that column a `FLOAT` and implicitly casting your string number of `123.456700` to that float type. Perhaps one more cast around that float cast back to a `varchar(20)` or whatever.

Comment: Your case expression doesn't make sense. Please [edit] your question to include sample data as DDL+DML (Create table and insert statements) and expected results. Be sure to include sample data for both cases that should be handled by the `case` expression.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, I've edited it with sample data. Thanks.

Comment: Your requirement does not make much sense now.  Do you want to _retain_ the trailing zeroes, or _remove_ them?  If you want to retain them as text, then use my answer or something along those lines.  If you want to remove the trailing zeroes, then just cast to a number, as you were already doing in the beginning.

Comment: Tim, I want it work interchangeably depending on the flag. When the flag is true, I want the zeros be removed; if the flag is false, I want the zeros be retained. That's why I require the case statement. It works fine as a standalone as you suggested. But when I try to bring it to a case statement, it doesn't function properly. In the example I put, as the flag is true, it should remove the zeros. But it doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

As @JNevill commented, what is happening here is that an implicit conversion is happening in the `ELSE` branch of your `CASE` expression, converting the string literal into a float, thereby removing the trailing zeroes when it gets printed.  One option would be to cast the `IF` portion to `VARCHAR`:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN 1=0
         THEN CAST(CAST(123.45000 AS decimal(6,2)) AS varchar(max))  -- a string
         ELSE '123.456700' END  -- also a string
```

### Demo

Note that in certain versions of SQL (other than yours) your `CASE` expression would not even run without error.  It just so happens that a silent conversion is taking place here.

Comment: Thanks @Tim.  It works in the demo you showed. But it doesn't remove the zeros at all in a table. It doesn't recognize the flag at all. Please look at the example code I put above. (I updated the question with it; and put it as an answer). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove trailing zeroes from a `decimal` data type. The [`decimal/numeric`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) data types are fixed point data type:

> Numeric data types that have fixed precision and scale. Decimal and numeric are synonyms and can be used interchangeably.

This means that the decimal point is in a fixed position within the stored number, unlike `float` and `read` which are floating point data types - so for a `decimal(9,2)` there will *always* be two digits to the right of the decimal point - and for `numeric(5,3)` where will *always* be three digits to the left of the decimal point.

If precision is not very important, you can convert to [`float`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) - but you should be aware that unlike `decimal`, `float` is an approximate data type.
Please note that you would still have to convert both branches of the `case` statement to a `varhcar` otherwise SQL Server will implicitly convert both branches to `float` and it will look like the flag is being ignored.

```
DECLARE @flag INT = 1

SELECT 
        CASE WHEN @flag = 1 
            THEN CAST(CAST(amount AS float) as varchar(30))
            ELSE CAST(amount as varchar(30)) 
        END As [Remove trailing zeros],

        -- This is to show the opposite branch
        CASE WHEN @flag = 0 
            THEN CAST(CAST(amount AS float) as varchar(30))
            ELSE CAST(amount as varchar(30)) 
        END As [Include trailing zeros]
FROM #tablea
```

Results:

```
Remove trailing zeros   Include trailing zeros
1.1                     1.10
1                       1.00
0.9                     0.90
0.09                    0.09
```

Answer (score 0):

@Tim, thanks. It works in the demo you showed. But it doesn't remove the zeros at all in a table. It doesn't recognize the flag at all. Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE #tablea 
(item CHAR(2), name VARCHAR(10), amount DECIMAL(9,2)) 

INSERT INTO #tablea 
VALUES ('AB', 'D1', 1.10), 
       ('AB', 'D2', 1.00), 
       ('AB', 'D3', 0.90), 
       ('AB', 'D4', 0.09)    

DECLARE @flag INT = 1

SELECT CASE WHEN @flag = 1 
THEN CAST(CAST(amount AS DECIMAL(6,2)) AS VARCHAR(max))
ELSE amount END 
FROM #tablea
```